# Solidity test file reaches gas limit due to imports

Tags: solidity, truffle, testing, ganache

I have a sol contract `X.sol` and a sol test file `TestX.sol`. `X.sol` is large: ~4m Gas after optimisation

`TextX.sol` compiles, migrates and executes tests fine when just executing a single test - `testY`, however.. when I add a `testZ` function and add even 1 line of (basic) solidity.. I get the following error:

> 1) TestX
>          "before all" hook: prepare suite:
>        Error: while migrating TestX: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: out of gas

However if I leave the body of `testZ` empty, it migrates fine.

Basically, I just want to know if there is a way to get visibility on the size of the compiled test file? Or a way to optimise gas usage?

```
networks: {
  development: {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 8545,
    gas: 6130000,
    network_id: '*'
  }
},
solc: {
  optimizer: {
    enabled: true,
    runs: 200
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this for Truffle:

```
development: {
    host:       'localhost',
    port:       8545,
    network_id: '*',
    gasPrice:   0x1,
    gas:        0x1fffffffffffff
}
```

And this for Ganache:

```
--port=8545
--gasPrice=0x1
--gasLimit=0x1fffffffffffff
```

Comment: Cheers, manually changing gas limit for Ganache was sufficient

Comment: I would like to add that I generally do not recommend this mode of operation. Better use "real" gas-price and gas-limit (i.e., similar to what's used on mainnet). Otherwise, you might be in for a surprise when you go to production. In short, use it in solidity-coverage if you must, but try to avoid using it in truffle.