# Truffle v5 runs out of gas but Truffle v4 deploys the contract

Tags: solidity, truffle, remix, truffle-migration, truffle-deployment

Truffle v4 used to deploy the contract successfully, but Truffle v5 `truffle migrate` command fails.

My process to deploy:

```
1) delete buidl/ folder

2) truffle compile

3) truffle migrate
```

**Truffle v5**

The error I get is:

```
Error:  *** Deployment Failed ***
"ContractName" ran out of gas. Something in the constructor (ex: infinite loop) 
caused gas estimation to fail. Try:
* Making your contract constructor more efficient
* Setting the gas manually in your config or as a deployment parameter
* Using the solc optimizer settings in 'truffle.js'
* Setting a higher network block limit if you are on a
 private network or test client (like ganache).

at C:\Users\dziug\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\truffle-deployer\src\deployment.js:364:1
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
Truffle v5.0.0 (core: 5.0.0)
Node v10.4.0
```

My **truffle-config.js** looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 8545,
      network_id: '*',
  compilers: {
    solc: { 
      version: "^0.4.24",
      optimizer: {
        enabled: true,
        runs: 200
      }
    }
  }
```

Then I installed **truffle v4** and tried to migrate the same contract:

```
1) npm uninstall -g truffle

2) npm install -g truffle@4.1.15

3) delete buidl/ folder

4) truffle compile

5) truffle migrate
```

And it works. I can deploy it on the rinkeby too.

Remix doesn't deploy it with

> javascript VM: "creation of ContractName errored: transaction
>   execution failed"

However, I can deploy it to Rinkeby through Remix

I need this contract to be deployed with truffle v5, because I will develop Solidity 0.5.* contracts that will communicate with the one I am trying to deploy right now, otherwise I won't be able to test with javascript.

The contract I am trying to deploy is: https://github.com/cryptocopycats/awesome-cryptokitties/tree/master/contracts

with couple fixes and additions. Contract starts from KittyCore.sol

Comment: Similar question [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/64256/16043).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check @goodvibration [answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/64256/solidity-test-file-reaches-gas-limit-due-to-imports). It should work in most instances.

*I don't recommend the answer that I will share below, it will ignore the [EIP-170](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-170.md), hopefully there is a better answer*

I was only able to make it migrate using:
`ganache-cli --gasLimit=0x1fffffffffffff --allowUnlimitedContractSize -e 1000000000`

**--allowUnlimitedContractSize:** "Allows unlimited contract sizes while debugging. By enabling this flag, the check within the EVM for contract size limit of 24KB (see EIP-170) is bypassed. Enabling this flag will cause ganache-cli to behave differently than production environments."

**-e {number}:** gives that much ether to all 10 accounts

My **truffle-config.js** looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 8545,
      network_id: '*',
      gas: 0x1fffffffffffff
    },
  }
}
```

Comment: Cheers! It worked

Comment: How to do the same with Ganache UI ?

Answer (score 0):

Your truffle-config.js file is not correct. Have a look at: 
https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/releases/tag/v5.0.0-beta.0#bring-your-own-compiler

For the correct format for the truffle-config.js file.

Comment: Instead of saying that the config file is not correct, it would be way more useful if you pointed out what is wrong with it, and provide a fix, instead of referring to a fairly broad documentation where it's hard to figure out what's wrong with it.

Comment: I didn't mean to be unhelpful, your truffle-config.js file doesn't seem to be correct. I was just speaking plainly. The documentation is the best place to check, and the correct format is right at the top. 
Specifically: 
It's not a valid javascript object for one thing (6 open curly braces, 3 close curly braces) and it should have a format like this: 

module.exports = {
  networks: {
    ... etc ...
  },
  compilers: {
     solc: {
       version: <string>  // ex:  "0.4.20". (Default: Truffle's installed solc)
     }
  }
};

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your config:

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 8545,
      network_id: '*',
  compilers: {
    solc: { 
      version: "^0.4.24", // this line
      optimizer: {
        enabled: true,
        runs: 200
      }
    }
  }
```

If you want to use v5, you have to change to appropriate `solc` version, like `0.5.0`

Comment: This is incorrect. That's the Solidity version which is a different thing than the Truffle version.

Answer (score 0):

On Ganache, set Gas Limit as 8721975 and in Truffle config, set the gas as 8721974

```
   development: {
     host: "127.0.0.1",     // Localhost (default: none)
     port: 7545,            // Standard Ethereum port (default: none)
     network_id: "*",       // Any network (default: none)
     gas: 8721974
    },
```